# DBIx::Class Remove Relationship

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a bunch of DBIx::Class modules created automatically by [dbicdump](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3A%3AClass%3A%3ASchema%3A%3ALoader).  It does a great job, but is there a way to remove some relationships it creates?  Or prevent a select few from being created?  I saw `skip_relationships`, but that's an all-or-nothing.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you give an example of a relationship you want to remove?  It may cause more problems removing it than ignoring it.  If it's an enforced constraint, the inability to explore it through the model may cause some hard to reason about errors down the line.

Comment: That's a good point, it is a foreign key column, but it's just one that I'd never have need to access directly.  A table has two columns pointing to the same table, just to establish relationships based on extra information.  So, a bit like a dictionary where I'd have no call to use it in reverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source of [`DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::RelBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/source/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07039/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/RelBuilder.pm#L379), it seems that this isn't possible. But I think it's a useful feature that should be easy to implement. You might want to open a [wishlist ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader).